# pop-up named Script Error displays on running selenium RC - Grid in MS Virtual PC 2007

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid, vpc

I am running selenium grid using testNG suite. When i run RC in localhost and other systems works well. But when i run in Microsoft Virtual PC 2007, system displays a pop up named 'Script Error'. Please check the attached [image].

I have turned off pop up blocker setting for IE browser and still the same error. I am stuck at this point, Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Response found at http://manfredlange.blogspot.in/2009/11/ie8-and-selenium-rc-tests-wont-execute.html

open Eclipse as administrator and this problem is resolved :-)

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately happens occasionally.  You should ensure you're using the latest Selenium release and then report any issues on the issue tracker.  The project page is http://selenium.googlecode.com/